# Paper clip in rails js format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have a `form_for` that has a file attachment. I am using `paperclip` to upload the file.

The model, together with the attachment gets saved but it can not respond in the `respond_to` format. The error message says: `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

Below is my code

```
<%= form_for @student, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>

def create
  @student = Studnet.new(student_params)
  if @student.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render 'edit'}
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render 'new'}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show the code of edit?

Comment: It is similar with the 'new' code:                                                                                                                 <%= form_for @student, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>

Comment: Are you sure that you can respond js and render a view?

Answer (score 0):

you call should be a js ..rather than html/json.something like:-

```
Started GET "/images/user_8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-10 07:17:45 -0700
Processing by ImagesController#show as js
```

can you see the similar in the server logs?